# Confidence interval for percentage of recyclable vs non-recyclable trash?

Tags: proportion, percentage

Let's say I have several samples of trash.

- Sample A: 1042 pounds of trash, 37% of which is recyclable
- Sample B: 311 pounds of trash, 45% of which is recyclable
- many more samples like this

I've got about 100 samples. How can I get a confidence interval for the percentage of trash that is recyclable? It seems like I have multiple p-hats, but the formulas I've seen use only one p-hat. I also feel that just averaging the percentages together for one p-hat isn't the right approach either. Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How many pounds of trash do you have? How many pounds are recyclable? // Is there some reason not to consider all of the trash combined together?

Comment: The samples all come from different facilities, but I'm honestly not sure if that's reason enough.  I guess I really overthinked this and I'll just add them together and use p-hat +/- z*sqrt(p(1-p)/n).  n being the number of samples I added together.

Comment: It depends on what question(s) you have, what assumptions you’re willing to make, and how complex of a model you’re willing to make. For instance, is there any kind of geographic clustering of the facilities, such as X-percent being in San Francisco, Y-percent being in San Diego, and Z-percent being in Toronto?